# Simpler way to pattern match on null (C#)

Tags: c#

Is there a simpler way to write this type of code?

```cs
while (true) {
    int? temp = f();

    if (temp is null)
    {
        break;
    }

    int x = temp.Value;
    // ... use x
}
```

Comment: `if (temp is not { } x) break;`

Comment: @JL0PD I'm pretty sure if you're going to go that route then `if (temp is not int x) break;` is infinitely more readable than those empty curly braces.

Comment: As a side note, I hope these are not your real variable and method names. Otherwise I would change them first of all to make the code a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern match expression itself can be like this:

```
    if (temp is not int x)
    {
        break;
    }

    // ... use x
```

Or you can change the entire loop to be like this:

```
while (f() is int x)
{
   // ... use x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
int? x1, x2;
while ((x1 = f()) is { })
    x2 = x1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
for (int? temp; (temp = f()) != null; ){
 // use temp
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. `f()` returns a nullable int, so you can't assign it to `temp`, which is a non-nullable int.

Comment: Well, it's simple enough to add the nullable variable, I edited the code

Comment: Now it compiles, but `temp` is nullable, so everywhere you use it you have to refer to `temp.Value`.